# How to get Facebook.ui Feed 'dialog'/'popup' to display Large preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working on facebook social sharing, and I have gotten it to work via 'dialog' & 'popup' modals.
My feed is Shared on Facebook feed with the newer Large display rectangle.

I've set up all the proper parameters such as:
method:
app_id:
name:
link:
picture:
caption:
description:
display:

my page renders meta-tags with og:image, og:image_secure_ssl, og:image:height, og:image:width, with their respective content="image/height/width"

I've used the facebook:debugger to freshly re-scrape/cache the url.

Using FB.ui(options...), there is no parameter for height/width to be sent to facebook.  My images meet the correct sizes of 1200x800+, as well as their aspect ratio of 1.9:1

What I want to achieve in my preview-modal is this:
Go to this website, and click on the round black facebook share icon:
http://www.violetgrey.com/violet-files/top-flight/the-golden-eye?icl=section_1_hero_v2_1&icn=hero_image
The much larger preview

My current preview-modal display currently is more like: 
Go to this website, and click on the facebook share blue button:
https://www.everlane.com/invite
The small square preview

I really like the bigger share modal preview, because it looks better imo.
Do you guys have any advice as to how I can proceed?

Comment: That other site you are referring to is using the Share dialog, whereas you are using the Feed dialog.

Comment: And btw., Facebook explicitly forbids you from rewarding people for sharing. Please go read their platform policy.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I haven't read their sharing rules with rewards, however, the website I'm working on doesn't reward people for sharing.  Thanks for the heads up!!

I've tried swapping over to:
method: "share", and even "share_open_graph"
But to no avail to get the larger preview modal display

Comment: Oh, so https://www.everlane.com/invite isn’t your site, but was meant as an example only? My apologies. (What they are doing – _“Tell your friends [and] Receive $25 of credit when friends make their first purchase.”_ – violates FB policies, if they base that on the FB shares.)

Comment: Yup, just an example to show how mine looks similar to their small version.

Comment: Did you use an image of the recommended dimensions and aspect ratio, as described in the docs?

Comment: Yup, image sizes are 12xx by 7xx, and very close to their aspect ratio. 
I followed the fb developer docs, best practices as found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Comment: so it seems that on some computers it shows the large modal display, and on mine is shows the smaller display.  head-scratcher ?_?

Comment: Facebook decides what image sizes to use when and where – not only for dialogs, but for the resulting post as well. Apart from providing images in the recommended dimensions and ratio, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

To get the large preview, you can either rely on the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) or open up the plain old https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=(http://yourURL.com/) in a popup. They both use the [Open Graph metadata](http://ogp.me/) you set in the `head`.

The [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4) can be used to override the OG meta, so you can specify a title, description, picture, but there's no way to set the picture's dimensions or the layout of the dialog...